# Create an object from an array

Tags: arrays, object, powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a string of data which I turn into an array thus:

```
$cfg_data = @(
"AppName1,data1",
"AppName2,data2"    
)
```

I then run a foreach query to work on each line at a time:

```
FOREACH($a in $cfg_data)
{
    $dataSplit = $a -split"(,)"
    $AppN = $dataSplit[0]
    $AppD = $dataSplit[2]

    #Do stuff here
}
```

But I want to convert this from a string to an Object, so I can add/remove additional items, 
and then run some more foreach statements, updating the different bits as I go.

I have got as far as:

```
FOREACH($a in $cfg_data)
{
    $dataSplit = $a -split"(,)"
    $AppN = $dataSplit[0]
    $AppD = $dataSplit[2]

        $objHere = @(
            @{ 
                appItem = "$AppN";
                appData = "$AppD";
             }) 
}
```

But when I check `$objHere` it just has the last entry in it (AppName2, datat2)

I tried adding:

```
$b=0
```

and

```
$objHere[$b]
```

but then I get

```
Array assignment failed because index '1' was out of range.
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Thats because you overwrite the object every time you loop, add it to an object array inside your loop and you should be fine (syntax: $arr+=$objhere)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By declaring `$objHere` in the loop, you overwrite the value on each iteration. You need to initialise an empty array outside the loop and append to it from within the loop:

```powershell
$objHere = @()

foreach($a in $cfg_data)
{
    $dataSplit = $a -split"(,)"
    $AppN = $dataSplit[0]
    $AppD = $dataSplit[2]

    $objHere += 
        @{ 
           appItem = "$AppN";
           appData = "$AppD";
         }
}
```

In addition, you're not actually creating an object, you're creating a hashtable. If you wanted to create an object instead, you could do this:

```powershell
$objHere = @()

foreach($a in $cfg_data)
{
    $dataSplit = $a -split"(,)"
    $AppN = $dataSplit[0]
    $AppD = $dataSplit[2]
    $objHere += New-Object PSObject -property @{appItem = "$AppN";appData = "$AppD";}
}
```

Giving:

```powershell
appItem  appData
-------  -------
AppName1 data1
AppName2 data2
```

Comment: you are a star. It seems so obvious once someone points out the mistakes. Cheers